# How to set certain option for a vim plugin window?

Tags: vim, nerdtree, vim-plugin

I use NerdTree Plugin and have `set cursorcolumn` in my vimrc file, but I don't want a column highlight in the NerdTreePlugin window, How can I do that?

Also, I do not want signs column show in the nerdtree window, how can I do that?

Much more common question, how to set or disable a specific option for a specific plugin window, e.g. NerdTree or Tagbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `cursorcolumn` in all buffers except for a few, use an `autocmd` in your vimrc to disable it for specific buffers, using `setlocal`.

For instance:

```
autocmd FileType nerdtree setlocal nocursorcolumn
```

Comment: Tagbar plugin handles these situations pretty well, Is there a way to tell a plugin window to not affect by any other options in vimrc? Eg, cursorline, cursorcolumn, colorcolumn and signcolumn, etc.